# Passing text from Javascript->HTML->PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a JS variable like this

```
totalItems = 'TOTAL ITEMS';
        if(rck > 0)
                totalItems = totalItems+" \nRack(s) "+rck;

        if(totflat > 0)
                totalItems = totalItems+" \nFlat Shelf(s) "+totflat;

        if(db > 0)
                totalItems = totalItems+" \nDisplay bar(s) "+db;

        if(totslan > 0)
                totalItems = totalItems+" \nSlanted shelf(s) "+totslan;
document.getElementById('totalitems').innerHTML = totalItems;
```

Here `totalitems` is my `<div>` id in HTML form. 
The text is printing in a single line, but I want them in each line like

```
TOTALITEMS
Rack(s) 2
Flat Shelf(s) 2
...
```

How to do this?
And my other question is I need to send that text in the same format to my PHP file.
How to post the text from div to PHP?
Any advices???
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `<br>` instead of `\n`. And for passing them to a PHP script you have multiple ways. first you can create a query to send them with JQuery, like:

```
data = "Rack="+rck+"&Flat_shelf="+totalFlat+"&db="+db+"&totslan="+totslan; //These are your variables that you want to send to PHP script
var saveData = $.ajax({
      type: 'POST'
      url: "page.php",
      data: data,
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(resultData) { alert("sent") }
});
saveData.error(function() { alert("Something went wrong"); });
```

Second you can create hidden input elements, and post them with a form.

Comment: User also asked how to send that text in the same format to my PHP file?

Comment: Oh, sorry, just about to fix it

Comment: @DeadMan, Hope everything is correct now. I was trying to be fast :D

Comment: Just tell the way to get that div value into the `data` variable also.

Comment: Variable names depends on what he has before presented script of him.

Comment: Just give a rough idea with a dummy variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Part 1: Replace `\n` with `<br/>` in your code.

Part 2: Need more info:

- What are you doing on the server side? (I am asking since in most
  cases you would be better off simply sending the values and simply
  reconstructing it in the same format on the server side. This avoids
  dependencies between server and client side logic)
- Are you using jQuery or some other Javascript library?

Answer (score 0):

To display it in your dive use the `<br>` instead of `\n` as suggested in other answers.

Then to send it to your PHP server use a XmlHttpRequest (aka AJAX request). In this case sending the text with the `\n` should not be a problem.